# Retrieve variants generated by Elasticsearch on ingest

Tags: elasticsearch, token, elasticsearch-analyzers

Elasticsearch versions 7 and 8.

When Elasticsearch ingests data, it generates certain phonetic keys for the tokens (and other types depending on the analyzer you specify).  Is there a way to retrieve and view these for a given document via query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [analyze API on specific index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html#analyze-api-specific-index-ex) and provide the text of your field in your documents to see the tokens generated by Elasticsearch.

Please refer to the examples given in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks - while this is certainly partially what I'm after, I'm asking if it can be done against existing documents, for example pass `"analyze": True` as part of a query.

Comment: @Stpete111, `analyze` true won't show the tokens, it simply means that this field in question will go through the analysis phase, you have to use the `analyze` API if you want to see the actual tokens, hope this makes it clear.